# dim(X) must have a positive length in R for mean

Tags: r, dataframe, data-science

I want to compute average point or mean for each group, the code :

```
y <- factor(data[,4])
K<-length(levels(y)) 



 K
    Xk <-list()
    Xk <- split(X,y)
    gk<-list()
        for (k in 1:K){
        gk[[k]]<-matrix(apply(Xk[[k]],2,mean),ncol=1)
     }
```

How can i prevent this error ?

```
Error in apply(Xk[[k]], 2, mean) : dim(X) must have a positive length
```

Data :

```
X1  X2  X3  group
7   26  84  "1"
9   28  84  "1"
8   27  81  "2"
10  23  81  "2"
11  25  80  "3"
12  24  79  "3"
13  29  78  "3"
```

Comment: Is `data` a matrix or a dataframe ? You may try `result <- aggregate(.~group, data.frame(data), mean)`

Comment: Data is a dataframe

Comment: And what `X` is `split(X,y)` being applied upon?

Comment: x is the matrix of columns X1,X2,X3 and y is the matrix of the group column. So, I will have Xk = 7,26,84,9,28,84 for the group 1...

Comment: I have this result for Xk

> Xk
$`"1"`
[1]  7  9 26 28 84 84

$`"2"`
[1]  8 10 27 23 81 81

$`"3"`
[1] 11 12 13 25 24 29 80 79 78

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.